# Как правильно задать тип chart-а c помощью delphi

Tags: delphi, excel, vba, диаграммы

Есть часть кода на Delphi:

```
chart:=sheet.chartobjects.add(270,205,397,220);
chart.chart.charttype:=4;
chart.Chart.SetSourceData(Sheet.Range['A3:B34']);
```

который выводит в Excel график (диаграмму):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужен другой тип графика, через макрос (excel-vba) он выглядит так:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(332, xlLineMarkersStacked).Select
```

Вопрос: какой код на Delphi должен выполняться вместо этой строчки, чтоб он вывел мне вот такой тип графика:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам достаточно заменить

```
chart.chart.charttype:=4;
```

на

```
chart.chart.charttype:=66; // xlLineMarkersStacked = 66
```

чтобы сменить тип диаграммы на нужный.

Если часто приходится использовать построение диаграмм в Excel внутри Delphi-программ, стоит завести модуль, где будут перечислены основные константы. Вот все [константы энумерации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241008%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) для диаграмм Excel, скопируйте их в новый юнит, оформите как `const` и вам проще будет транслировать макросы Excel в код Delphi.

Comment: спасибо за помощь)

Comment: еще один момент: как убрать форму легенду?

Comment: @Амирхон в вашем коде так: chart.Chart.haslegend:=false;

Comment: Все проблема решена, еще раз большое спасибо Вам))

Comment: @Амирхон Всегда пожалуйста :)

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста а как задать ширину линии?

Comment: @Амирхон поиграйтесь с макросом, определитесь, какое значение вам нужно, а затем меняйте свойство диграммы ChartArea.Border.LineStyle:=вашезначение (integer);

Comment: @ Viktor Tomilov вот код: With Selection.Format.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .Weight = 3.75

Comment: @ Viktor Tomilov не смог, и ваш опробовал не получается(

Comment: @Амирхон Вам толщину линии графика? Ну, вы же сами только что привели. Просто отталкивайтесь от вашего же кода. У вас это будет так:   chart.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.Weight:=3.75; (1) - номер графика

Comment: спасибо еще раз, выручили)