# Как задать left position диаграммы во время экспорта в excel?

Tags: delphi, excel, vba, диаграммы

Делаю отчет в Excel-е с диаграммой на delphi.
У него фиксированная позиция:

```
chart := sheet.chartobjects.add(270,205,397,220);
```

Как сделать, чтоб диаграмма началась с нужной мне колонки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Амирхон, чтобы вам проще было работать в Delphi (да и в других программах) с офисными продуктами, постарайтесь разобраться в иерархии объектов. Как только вы разберетесь, многие вещи сразу станут понятны. Я не могу посоветовать вам какую-то конкретную книгу, поскольку сам когда-то разбирался методом научного тыка, но, возможно, кто-то другой посоветует.*

*Хороший тон - использовать инструменты разработчика, они очень сильно помогают. В офисе 2003 и ранее - это запись макросов с последующим их анализом, позже - то же самое + использование вкладки Разработчик (её необходимо предварительно включить в настройках).*

Итак, `Chart` входит в семейство `Shapes`, которое принадлежит `Sheet` (принадлежащий, в свою очередь, `Book`). Фишка в том, что к одному и тому же объекту можно обратиться по-разному, OLE это позволяет. И тот факт, что у каждого программиста есть свои любимые подходы, порождает массу непонятного. Но стоит прочувствовать иерархию, всё становится на свои места.

У меня подход несколько иной, чем у вас. Я вначале определяю объект, а уже затем задаю его свойства. На мой взгляд, так удобнее. Допустим, мы создали лист в Excel и заполнили несколько ячеек для диаграммы данными:

```
Excel:=CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
Excel.Visible:=True;
Book:=Excel.Workbooks.Add; // мне не жалко переменных для каждого объекта
Sheet:=Book.Worksheets[1]; // поскольку дальше проще работать
for i := 1 to 5 do
  begin
    Sheet.Cells[i, 1].FormulaR1C1:=i;
    Sheet.Cells[i, 2].FormulaR1C1:=cos(i); // пусть будет косинус
  end;
```

Все переменные здесь - `OleVariant`. Теперь создаем диаграмму:

```
ch:=Sheet.Shapes.AddChart;
```

Я специально выбрал для диаграммы переменную ch, а не chart, поскольку у диаграммы несколько уровней свойств, в том числе и свойство Chart, многие начинающие путаются в этом. Далее:

```
Ch.Name := 'График 1'; // обзовём диаграмму так
Ch.Chart.ChartType := xlLineMarkers; // тип диаграммы
```

Типы диаграмм мы обсуждали в [Как правильно задать тип chart-а c помощью delphi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/770613/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF-chart-%D0%B0-c-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-delphi/770624#770624). Либо вы поступаете так, как я порекомендовал, либо можно использовать один из встроенных модулей Delphi, например, `ExcelXP` или `Excel2010`, в которых эти константы определены. Отмечу, что, чтобы изменить некоторые свойства диаграммы, например, название, я обращаюсь непосредственно к переменной ch, а вот для работы с графиком я должен уже обращаться к свойству `Chart`.

Ну, а теперь вернемся к нашему основному вопросу. Изменим координаты. Координаты - свойства непосредственно диаграммы, это `Left` и `Top`. Задаются они в пикселях, причём только для левого верхнего угла, а правый нижний уже определяется `Width` и `Height` (шириной и высотой, причём, как правило, в долях экрана, а не в пикселях). Так как вам нужно поместить диаграмму не в координатах пикселей, а в координатах ячеек, то нам нужно вначале их рассчитать:

```
Ch.Left := Sheet.Range['A1:D1', EmptyParam].Width + 2; 
Ch.Top := Sheet.Range['E1:E3', EmptyParam].Width + 2;
```

Я поместил, таким образом, свою диаграмму в ячейку E4, сместив её край на 2 пикселя.  Кстати, тот же самый результат можно получить по-другому:

```
Ch.Left := Sheet.Range['E4', EmptyParam].Left + 2; 
Ch.Top := Sheet.Range['E4', EmptyParam].Top + 2;
```

Что ещё раз демонстрирует разные подходы.

Comment: я только начинаю программировать...) спасибо Вам, очередной раз большое, за столь доходчивый и понятный ответ)) очень помогли)

Comment: @Амирхон всегда пожалуйста! Стремление знать больше - очень хорошее качество.